# Include filtering and auto column width

Tags: python, excel, pandas

What I have works perfect but I would like the ability to show a filter on the top row and auto generate the width of each column

```
def save(df, sheet_name, data, mode='w'):
    with pd.ExcelWriter(df, mode=mode, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index = False)
        #data.to_excel(writer, 'sheet_2')


file_base = '.xlsx'
file = 'name' + file_base
sheet1_name = 'name'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you.  I want to add a filter button in the top row and I would like each column to be auto adjusted according to the width of the columns. Below is a code that works for me but I would like write a function to use for most of my scripts

Comment: writer= pd.ExcelWriter('df.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = sheet_name, index = False)
df_Workbook  = writer.book
Contractor2_Worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
(max_row, max_col) = Contractor2.shape
df_Worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1)
df_Worksheet.set_column('A:D', 25)
writer.save()